# Cannot install Wordpress Multisite (Network) on a custom port

Tags: apache, xampp, wordpress

I'm running a website at `http://localhost:8080/sitename`. However, when I'm trying to create a network of sites with wordpress, I'm getting the following error under `Tools-> Network`:

```
ERROR: You cannot install a network of sites with your server address.
You cannot use port numbers such as :8080.
```

I tried to create a virtual host and a fake domain but I can't make it work.
How can I solve that?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found temporary solution:

running "netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0.80" in CMD will show you wich service is using the port 80. If PID is 4 it means that port 80 is used by the system (propably IIS or web matrix if it is installed - this was my case). i changed the port IIS was using from IIS Manager and i also deactivated MsDepSvc service (Web Matrix) which was also using port 80. After that i reconfigured apache to work in port 80 and everything worked OK!

Answer (score 54):

At this moment, Wordpress only seem to support 80 and 443 ports. A temporary possible workaround to use any custom (i.e. http `8080`) port:

1. Open `wp-admin/includes/network.php` and find the section of code where it mentions `array( ':80', ':443' )` and  add `:8080` too in that array.
2. After completing setup of network, you might need in `wp-config` to adjust to such:
   `define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com'. (stristr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'wp-login.php') ? '':':8080') );`
3. As noted in comments (thanks) after creating first sub-site, it might have port number embedded in domain name, so try to enter Mysql Database (i.e. try **hosting's phpMyAdmin**, or even [installed plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-phpmyadmin-extension/) before starting procedure) and in `_blogs` & `_site`& `_options` tables, to adjust homepage urls of subsites(i.e. separate port number from domain).
4. That's all. Login again to your project.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea, and I tried it with wordpress-4.9.8-en_US. Sure that hack bypasses WP restriction and the first site (auto added) works. But the second site I added was broken, something with the URLs, I was getting 404s. I tried that setup several times, I end up changing my setup to work with localhost instead. So far so good.

Comment: The issue with bypassing the check is that WP is not designed to use custom ports for multi-sites so the blogs (sub-sites) hosts get messed up in the DB. After you switch to multi-site or create a new site, you need to go to your db admin page (e.g. phpMyAdmin) and fix the blogs domain in the wp_blogs table. Basically WP failed to add a colon between the host and port; just have to add it-> `localhost8080` becomes `localhost:8080`. Then On the site's settings add the missing colon to the siteurl and home urls.

Comment: For localhost, this answer is enough.

Comment: I think there may be a little more to it. See this article on the Benohead Blog: https://benohead.com/blog/2014/05/30/wordpress-running-multisite-different-port/.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, WP is not designed to use custom ports for multi-sites so the blogs (sub-sites) hosts get messed up in the DB.

My solution: After you switch to multi-site or create a new site, you need to go to your db admin page (e.g. phpMyAdmin) and fix the blogs domain in the `wp_blogs` table. Basically WP failed to add a colon between the host and port; just have to add it-> localhost8080 becomes localhost:8080.
So, on the site's settings add the missing colon to the siteurl and home urls.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to functions.php seems to work:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'wp_normalize_site_data', function( $data ) {
    $data['domain'] = str_replace('8080', ':8080', $data['domain']);
    $data['domain'] = str_replace('::', ':', $data['domain']);
    return $data;
}, 50, 1 );
```

Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21077#comment:32